# Java via proxy in docker container

Tags: java, docker, networking, docker-compose

I have container with java app and i try to force use proxy for this app. In docker container proxy is work right (i checked via curl). But when i send my request in requestbin, i see server ip, but not proxy ip (server ip ends 37, proxy 18).

This is curl from container:

```
curl 2ip.ru
x.x.x.18
```

And in requestbin i get this ip:

[image]

This is my JAVA_OPTS:

```
-Xms512M -Xmx2048M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -XX:+UseParallelGC -Djava.util.prefs.systemRoot=/app/.java -Djava.util.prefs.userRoot=/app/.java/.userPrefs -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dcom.sun.security.enableCRLDP=true -Dcom.ibm.security.enableCRLDP=true -Dtls_prohibit_disabled_validation=false -Djava.util.prefs.syncInterval=9999 -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005 -Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=10.0.1.13 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8081
```

And in docker-compose i use following envs:

```
http_proxy="http://10.0.1.13:8081"
https_proxy="http://10.0.1.13:8081"
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Are you sure your Java app listens to those `java.net` proxy options? Not all Java networking libraries will do that. You may have to make configuration for those libraries specifically.